# Flutter Menu App that gets pictures from firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a flutter app that is a menu for a restaurant. Now the problem is that I want to get the pictures from firebase. Currently, if you open the app, the pictures take time to load and you can see that with your eyes, it is a bit annoying and not practical regarding bandwidth data usage.

Is there any chance I can cache the images when I get them from firebase and than appear instantly? I request the links of the images once the page is open using a future and display them with a `CachedNetworkImageProvider()` with the image URL but that still takes time to load the images. Is there a way to download all the data in the firebase at once when you open the app and not check every time you open the app?

Answer (score 1):

for all apps that require fetching images from a remote location, what i have been doing so far is download the image locally and use the local image instead of the remote one if it exists locally, from my knowledge cachedNetworkImage only caches the image after fetching when the app is currently running and refetches the image when the user restarts the app.

Please if you do find another way to cache images that would be cool and remove a lot of boiler plate code, please do post it, thanks.

Comment: Hey, i found something. Using istead of 
CachedNetworkImageProvider() 
use CachedNetworkImage() 
also check this video out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7YtzC48SUg

Now the app works offline, I think by default the images get stocked in cache for 15 days but you can change it to even more.